# Ravendb Search Query Failed

Tags: ravendb, nosql

Here is index class

```
public class Facility_SearchTerm : AbstractIndexCreationTask<FacilityApplication>
{
    public Facility_SearchTerm()
    {
        Map = facilities => from facility in facilities
                            select new
                            {
                                facility.FacilityName
                            };

        Indexes.Add(x => x.FacilityName, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
    }
}
```

And here is a simple query

```
var query = session.Advanced.DocumentQuery<FacilityApplication, Facility_SearchTerm>()
                    .Statistics(out statsRef)
                    .Search(s => s.FacilityName, "abc")
                    .Skip(size * (page - 1))
                    .Take(size);
```

What is wrong? I got the error

`"Query failed. See inner exception for details. at Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.Query(String index, IndexQuery query, String[] includes, Boolean metadataOnly, Boolean indexEntriesOnly)`

Comment: What's the inner exception? Your code works fine for me in 3.0.3800 (with a very basic entity 'FacilityApplication')

Comment: Thanks, I solved. It don't execute index by itself.  It worked after running `new Facility_SearchTerm().Execute(store)`